# Handle page refreshes when you're using React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

**Issue:**
When I go to the root URL initially, the router renders the correct page. Navigating works fine as well. However, when I hit `refresh`, the app crashes with the following error:

```
instrument.js:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

This is the function in `instrument.js:112`. `computedStates` is `undefined`.

```
/**
 * Runs the reducer on invalidated actions to get a fresh computation log.
 */
function recomputeStates(computedStates, minInvalidatedStateIndex, reducer, committedState, actionsById, stagedActionIds, skippedActionIds) {
  // Optimization: exit early and return the same reference
  // if we know nothing could have changed.
  if (minInvalidatedStateIndex >= computedStates.length && computedStates.length === stagedActionIds.length) {
    return computedStates;
  }
```

When I do `localStorage.clear()` and refresh the page, the app comes back again.

**Packages that might be responsible for the issue:**

```
"react-router": "^2.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-localstorage": "^0.4.0",
```

**What's the best way to handle page refreshes when you are using react router?**

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, React Router does not have issues with page refreshing. It sounds like you might be having a problem with local storage getting into a state that is problematic when you refresh the page. I would suggest examining the contents of your local storage after you initially load the page.